# Dart RegExp word boundary equivalent

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

I try to match words and sentences that include exactly word "world" in my flutter application. I think that the best way to do this it to use word boundaries. My regex looks like this:

```
String str = "world";
var regexp = RegExp("\b($str)\b", caseSensitive: false);
```

But it does not work. This is the output:

```
regexp.hasMatch("Hello World"); //false
regexp.hasMatch("World"); //false
regexp.hasMatch("worlds"); //false as expected
```

Does \b not work in Dart? Does anyone know how to achieve desired behavior? I can't find any information about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Dart [regex documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html);

> Dart regular expressions have the same syntax and semantics as JavaScript regular expressions.

If you are using `RegExp` in JavaScript, then a word boundary would actually be represented by `\\b`, i.e. we need to add an extra escape to the `\b` word boundary:

```
String str = "world";
var regexp = RegExp("\\b($str)\\b", caseSensitive: false);
regexp.hasMatch("Hello World"); // true
```

Note that you should generally avoid using `RegExp` if possible, and instead use regex literals.  The reason for this is that literals relax and make the regex syntax simpler.

Comment: Hi, I've seem the documentation, and searched how to write this regex in JavaScript. Unfortunately I didn't realize that I need to escape this. Thanks a lot.