# Highlighting certain part of InlineSpans in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, highlight, textspan

I m developing a e book application with data that consists some  custom tags like  < t >, < nm >, < ar >, < bs >,< mean > and these tags wrapped with < t >

My text like below;

```
< t > < title >İkinci Lem’a< /title >< t > < bs > ﷽ < /bs >< t > < ar >اِذْ نَادٰي رَبَّهُٓ اَنّ۪ى مَسَّنِىَ الضُّرُّ وَاَنْتَ اَرْحَمُ الرَّاحِم۪ينَ< /ar >< t > < t ><nm>1</nm><t>\nSabır kahramanı Hazret-i Eyyub Aleyhisselâmın şu < t >< mean >münâcât< /mean >< t >ı, hem < t >< mean >mücerreb< /mean >< t >, hem tesirlidir. <t><nm>2</nm><t>Fakat ayetten <t><mean>iktibas</mean><t> <mean>suret</mean><t>inde, bizler, <t><mean>münâcât</mean><t >ımızda\t\t\t\t < t >< ar >رَبّ۪ى اِنّ۪ى مَسَّنِىَ الضُّرُّ وَاَنْتَ اَرْحَمُ الرَّاحِم۪ينَ< / ar>
```

I split text with  tag and according to corresponding tag I create Text or widget spans according to tag. then I want to make highlight some text without concerning what kind of span or textStyle data has. I tried many methods but cant success.

I tried to split reference words that will be highlighted no success.
I splitted words  and checked if reference string consists. that gives partial solution but it also highlihgts different parts of text which is not intended to highlihgt.

my reference string is :

```
String tt = "Hazret-i Eyyub Aleyhisselâmın meşhur kıssasının hülâsası şudur ki: \nPek çok yara bere içinde epey müddet kaldığı halde, o hastalığın azîm mükâfatını düşünerek, kemal-i sabırla tahammül edip kalmış.";
```

when I run it looks like this :

[image]

I just want only string equals to reference string has backround color.

this function where I split string and create spanlist

```
List<InlineSpan> getText(String t,) {
v = t.removeTags();

    List<InlineSpan> spans = [];

    List<String> words = t.split("<t>");

    for (var word in words) {
      if (isImage(word)) {
        spans.add(imageSpan(word,));
      } else if (isTitle(word).$1) {
        spans.add(titleSpan(word));
      } else if (hasMeaning(word)) {
        spans.add(meaningsSpan(word));
      } else if (isSn(word)) {
        spans.add(snSpan(word));
      } else if (isBesmele(word)) {
        spans.add(besmeleSpan(word));
      } else if (isYildiz(word)) {
        spans.add(yildizSpan(word));
      } else if (isNumber(word)) {
        spans.add(ayetNumberSpan(word));
      } else if (isHasiye(word)) {
        spans.add(hasiyeSpan(word));
      } else if (isArabic(word)) {
        spans.add(arapcaSpan(word));
      } else {
  
        spans.add(textSpan(word, word, null, null));
      }
    }

    return spans;
  }
```

this is the textSpan that returns custom styles according to tags words consist

```
TextSpan textSpan(String text, String word, double? height, Function(TapUpDetails)? onTapUp) {

    final list = text.split(" ");
    final length = list.length;
    return   TextSpan(
      children: list.mapIndexed((index, e){
var s = "";

if(index ==0){
 s = e;
}else if(index>0&& index==length){
  s = "${text.split(" ")[index - 1]??""} $e ";
}else if(index>0&& index<length-1){
  s = "${text.split(" ")[index - 1]??""} $e ${text.split(" ")[index +1]??""}";
}else if(index<length-1){
  s = "${text.split(" ")[index - 1]??""} $e ${text.split(" ")[index +1]??""}";
}

        return TextSpan(
         text: e + " ",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: getColor(word),
            fontSize: getFontSize(word),
            fontFamily: getFont(word),
            fontWeight: getFontWeight(word),
            fontStyle: getFontStyle(word),
            backgroundColor:  commentColor(s ),
            height: height),
            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTapUp = onTapUp);
     
      } ).toList()
      
 
       );

  }
```

I tried to split span text and tried to looked previous word or next word of every word and tried to find exact match in reference string. but no success

and this is the function I try to add highlight color to text style

```
Color? commentColor(String s){

    RegExp exp =  RegExp( "\\b$s\\b", caseSensitive: false, ); 
    bool contains = exp.hasMatch(tt);
  
    if(contains){
    return Colors.cyan;
  }

  return null;
}
```

any ide will be appriciated.

Note: stackoverflow removes tags when I write them without space

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're trying to match a `multi-line string` with a `regular expression` pattern designed to match a `single word`. The `\\b` word boundary anchors in your regular expression are meant to `match the boundaries of a single word`, not a `multi-line string`. And must have [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090443/dart-regexp-word-boundary-equivalent).

In the `commentColor` function, you're using the `RegExp` pattern `\\b($s)\\b`, which tries to match the whole string `tt` as a single word within the string `s`. Since `tt` contains newline characters and spans multiple lines, it doesn't match the word boundary conditions.

So If you want to check if `tt` appears anywhere in the string `s`, you can simply use the `contains` method without regular expressions:

```
Color? commentColor(String s) {
  bool contains = s.contains(tt);

  if (contains) {
    return Colors.cyan;
  }else{
    return null;
  }
}
```

and for case-insensitive search just replace the line:

```
bool contains = s.toLowerCase().contains(tt.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: thanks for help but the real problem is not this. the problem original string has tags so I cant make comparison with string with tags and string without text. so I am looking for the matches of splitted strings in tt string. as you can see in the picture there is different type spans. arabic letters are spans, some latin words also spans because there is dictionary that when user taps word a popup shows meaning of it. numbers are spans that stores meaning of arabic sentences. and also user might want highlight all combination of these spans. so I m looking solution for that.

Comment: The closest to my goal is looking for matches of splitted strings in tt string which is my reference string for the case.

Comment: If your original string have the tags you can make a regex for that and that will remove the tags, and after that you can make the comparison of the strings. simple.

Comment: You didnt understand my problem I think. if you check the code  You vill se I already have  v = t.removeTags(); line in code which is a string extension that remove tags.  I need to solve the problem in spans. not in whole text.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping all your spans in a parent and then searching on the [flattened text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/InlineSpan/toPlainText.html):

```dart
final wrapper = TextSpan(children: spans);
final haystack = wrapper.toPlainText();
```